# Combine two words in a corpus using R

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I'm trying to combine two words into one using the `content_transform` function as part of `tm` package in R.

For example, I've got location data and to create word clouds I need to combine "san jose", "san diego", "san francisco") otherwise "san" comes up as the most frequent word.

As far as I've gotten is creating a function, for example,

```
combineUK <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern)     
gsub(pattern,"UK",x,ignore.case = T))
```

However, creating functions for each town separately is unrealistic.

I was wondering whether there's any way I can implement the `paste()` function within `content_transform`?

So, perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide a full reproducible example (copy-paste-run-able), I don't know what you got and what you want. However, consider for example

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
par(mfrow = c(2,1), cex=.5)
txt <- c("hello san jose dudes", "welcome to san diego", "Did you like san francisco")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
wordcloud(corp, min.freq=1)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(function(x) gsub("(san).(\\w+)", "\\1\\2", x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
wordcloud(corp, min.freq=1)
```

[image]

Comment: lukeA's solution is OK but 1. I think she wanted _ between the tokens,  not just collapsing them.  But there is a harder problem.  What about San Luis Obispo and other names consisting of more than one token after San?

Comment: Good point. Maybe `cities <- grep(" ", maps::world.cities$name, val=T);cities_ <- gsub(" ", "_", cities);corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(function(x) { for (i in seq_along(cities)) x <- gsub(cities[i], cities_[i], x, ignore.case = TRUE); return(x) }))`?

Comment: Nice use of that resource.